# If Z is a function of Y then X,Y,Z forms a Markov's chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

This is a statement taken from Cover's book in information theory:

> If Z = f(Y) then X,Y,Z is a Markov's chain

Obviously, intuition tells you that if Z is computed from Y then it does not depend on X. How can I deduce this mathematically? Also, I need some clarification on f, I'm assuming that it is a measurable function, am I right?

Comment: just to clarify you can find the statement in Cover's book page 34

Comment: $E(f(Y)\mid X,Y)=f(Y)=E(f(Y)\mid Y)$. Also to be careful you should say "if Z is computed from Y then *conditionally on Y* it does not depend on X".